# What is the modern way to partition PostgreSQL across machines, when the data is "naturally partitionable"

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, high-availability

After several years of dwelling into the "NoSQL" space, now I have a problem that is quite "relational" in its nature.
Today I see data stores with quite different eyes than before. Things like Riak have spoiled me in a way that I can no more tolerate single points of failure, "down for maintenance" etc. Of course, (or I hope), I havent' lost my sanity totally. This is a a personal project that doesn't quite (or yet)  have extremely high requirements.

Most of the sharding solutions don't give me what I want (at least on a glimpse), probably because my problem is quite "easy" to solve. At least on conceptual level (ignoring the restraints that RDBMs themselves bring to the table).

1. I have a small amount of "shared" data, which can be duplicated freely. It doesn't have requirements of hard consistency. This can be stored in a dynamo-like database and will scale infinitely. But I still would like to go with a single database if possible.
2. I have lots of "per-user" data. That is - lots of users, with every user having data of absolutely reasonable size, really fit to be stored on a single PostgreSQL node. We are talking about 10s of thousands records at maximum.
3. I never need to query cross-user and I don't need cross-user atomicity.

This sounds extremely easy to achieve. At least when I'm looking at it with my "NoSQL eyes".

Here are my naive starter ideas:

1. At the very extreme, I could just serialize the whole user as a single Key/Value in Riak. Of course, constant de/serialization of several megabytes of data will be slow and that's why I'm considering using PostgreSQL. Lots of Riak K/Vs is a no-go, as I need atomicity/transactions within each user's data.
2. I could use an SQLite database per user, and use something like GlusterFS for the redundancy/availability. This is probably the solution I'm going to choose if I can't find something equally good using PostgreSQL. Pros: Can down/up scale really well; Cons: I'd prefer having PostgreSQL's types and strictness over SQLite

So, what I would ideally request from a PostgreSQL sharding solution:

1. Automatically keep several copies of every user's data around (on different machines). Be able to dynamically switch the master node per user/shard (if the previous master goes down).
2. Be able to dynamically up/down scale, by adding/removing server nodes. Mostly like Riak is able to do.
3. Do not require my application to know which nodes to talk to and when.

Comment: Hi loxs, how did you eventually solve this problem?

Comment: Application level partitioning with multiple data stores. Quite a mess actually :(. Really sad that something like this doesn't exist...

Answer (score 5):

[Postgres-XL](http://www.postgres-xl.org/overview/) is attempting to solve this as of 2014. They're aiming directly at big data on PostgreSQL, and they have developers from Stado onboard.

Comment: That looks super interesting.

Comment: And then there is also Postgres-XC: http://sourceforge.net/projects/postgres-xc/

Answer (score 4):

I think, the best option is [pgpool-II](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html). You can have up to 128 nodes and

1. It is possible to setup complex partitioning and data distribution rules
2. Support "Online Provisioning". Doesn't scale writes but it is read scalable
3. No sure, if possible out-of-the box. Maybe you need to use [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/)

Another option might be [Stado](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_mlodgenski/scaling-postresql-with-stado)